# How to call up a php file from another domain on the same server

Tags: php

I have several location specific websites and I have one file that lists all of the communities. I am calling it up on the other sites using

```
include (/otherdomain/file.php)
```

That has worked for years, but now I am having permmission issues.

Comment: What "permission issues"?  If it's worked for years then clearly it can work.  What's changed?  What is the error?

Comment: I don't see how it could work. When you call a PHP file on a different domain doesn't that mean it's rendered to a html file?

Comment: CORS would be the place to start. Executing PHP from another domain has never been possible.

Comment: The domains are all on the same server. It has worked for about 10 years, but stopped working a few months ago. The "include" command reverted to the server root, then followed the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

By default its not possible call php file from remote server because of security issues, and it's not recomended to do that.
but if you want to do that you must enable [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in php.ini file (set it to on) (it's disabled by default).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't specify that they are all on the same server.

Comment: In same server and diffrent domains? you mean using virtual machines in same server or one machine for all?

Comment: One machine for all

Comment: It worked fine until a couple of months ago. Even the technicians at our NOC are stumped.

Comment: Did you check file's permission? May be their permissions changed and can't be included.

Comment: Permission is 755

Comment: please write me complete what you did. write  your code with changed important informations of the code.

Comment: <?php include('/[server root level]/[remote folder]/public_html/communities.php'); ?>  Actual names have been replaced with brackets.